# Multiple table join with SUM(Distinct) and MAX

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables: `PART P` and `CUST_ORDER_LINE COL`. The code runs for each part until I put it together. Then I get the dreaded:

> “Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Column
>   'CUST_ORDER_LINE.LAST_SHIPPED_DATE' is invalid in the select list
>   because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the
>   GROUP BY clause.”

PART P

```
|ID | QTY_ON_HAND   | QTY_ON_ORDER |
  1            20               10
  1             5                0
  2             0                0
  3            10               20
  3            15                5
```

CUST_ORDER LINE COL

```
| PART_ID   | LAST_SHIPPED_DATE
        1     1/1/2010
        1     12/1/2013
        1     12/15/2014
        2     1/1/2015
        2     3/1/2015
        3     1/1/2013
```

OUTPUT NEEDED:

```
| ID    | Max_Date  | On_Hand   | On_Order
  1       12/25/2014       25           10              
  3       1/1/2013         25           25
```

QUERY

```
Select P.ID,
  COL.LAST_SHIPPED_DATE As Max_Date
  Sum(Distinct P.QTY_ON_HAND) As On_Hand,
  Sum(Distinct P.QTY_ON_ORDER) As On_Order
From PART P
  Inner Join CUST_ORDER_LINE COL 
   On P.ID = COL.PART_ID
  Inner Join 
   (Select CUST_ORDER_LINE.PART_ID,MAX(CUST_ORDER_LINE.LAST_SHIPPED_DATE) As Max_Date
   From CUST_ORDER_LINE  
   Group By PART_ID)col2
   On [ COL2].PART_ID = COL.PART_ID
    and col2.max_date = col.LAST_SHIPPED_DATE
Group By P.ID
Having Sum(Distinct P.QTY_ON_HAND) != 0
Order By P.ID
```

Comment: Shouldn't you remove a typo `.` in your Inner join part? `(Select.CUST_ORDER_LINE...` here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below query

```
select PART_ID, On_Hand,On_Order,max(LAST_SHIPPED_DATE) Max_Date
         from CUST_ORDER_LINE a inner join(
        select id,sum(QTY_ON_HAND) On_Hand ,sum(QTY_ON_ORDER) On_Order
         from PART group by id having sum(QTY_ON_HAND)!=0) t on a.PART_ID=t.ID
        group by PART_ID,On_Hand,On_Order
```

Comment: Thank you! That works and gets me one step further than I was. You did exactly what I asked for...I failed to add one additional detail.  I need all of the IDs from the PART table on the report and some are not in the CUST_ORDER_LINE table.

Comment: use left join instead of inner join,

Comment: For some reason that still isn't pulling all IDs from PART when I change it to left. For instance, if I query PART: "Select * from PART where ID =   '.0394-800' I get a row of data. With the query above changing the inner join to a left join, that row is not included.

Comment: with t as 
(select id,sum(QTY_ON_HAND) On_Hand ,sum(QTY_ON_ORDER) On_Order from PART group by id),
t1 as 
(select PART_ID, max(LAST_SHIPPED_DATE) Max_Date from CUST_ORDER_LINE group by PART_ID )
select * from t left join t1 on t.ID=t1.PART_ID

Answer (score 0):

You can either include `COL.LAST_SHIPPED_DATE` in your group by clause, or wrap the column in an aggregate function:

```
Select P.ID,
  max(COL.LAST_SHIPPED_DATE) As Max_Date
```

If you have a group by clause... any field that is not in the clause must be used only inside of some aggregation function in the selection output.